# Dúvidas na criação do meu App

Tags: java, android, api, maps

Estou criando um App e estou com algumas dúvidas, sou iniciante em Java e Android e algumas coisas não tenho idéia de como fazer.

Preciso criar uma forma, de mostrar na tela dos clientes, os "fornecedores" que estão por perto na hora em que ele acessa o aplicativo, como os "fornecedores" não são locais fixos, são como os taxis dos apps de taxi, preciso que isso seja atualizado a todo momento.Outra dúvida é com relação a encontrar o fornecedor mais próximo do cliente, minha idéia é criar uma tabela de localizações atualizadas no web service, fazer um calculo em toda tabela, usando a localização do cliente e ver a menor distancia, acredito que isso leve muito tempo e processamento.

Outra dúvida, é como autenticar o App no servidor? Não consigo entender essa parte, tudo que vejo sobre o HttpClient, não informa nada de usuário e senha além do Url.

Tenho mais dúvidas, mas essas é quais estão me matando no momento.

Comment: Acredito que você poderia criar um tópico para casa uma de suas dúvidas. Facilita para quem for responder.

Answer (score 1):

> Preciso criar uma forma, de mostrar na tela dos clientes, os "fornecedores" que estão por perto na hora em que ele acessa o aplicativo, como os "fornecedores" não são locais fixos, são como os taxis dos apps de taxi, preciso que isso seja atualizado a todo momento.

Pegue a latitude e a logitude de cada fornecedor e de cada cliente a cada 30 segundos, ou qualquer outro intervalo de tempo que você achar conveniente. Para os fornecedores que você sabe estar estacionários, você pode diminuir este tempo. Os fornecedores que não responderem (porque estão fora-de-área ou com o dispositivo desligado), você tira da lista e bota de novo quando voltarem a responder.

> Outra dúvida é com relação a encontrar o fornecedor mais próximo do cliente, minha idéia é criar uma tabela de localizações atualizadas no web service, fazer um calculo em toda tabela, usando a localização do cliente e ver a menor distancia, acredito que isso leve muito tempo e processamento.

Quantos são estes fornecedores? Se for menos do que uns 10000, isso deve ser rápido. Há formas de otimizar isso, por exemplo, divida a superficíe da Terra que te interessa em quadrados de 10 km x 10 km e coloque os fornecedores nestes quadrados. Então você pega somente os fornecedores que estão no quadrado do cliente e nos 8 quadrados vizinhos.

> Outra dúvida, é como autenticar o App no servidor? Não consigo entender essa parte, tudo que vejo sobre o HttpClient, não informa nada de usuário e senha além do Url.

Há várias formas de fazer isso, mas quase todas elas envolvem o famoso login e senha. Você envia o login+senha para o servidor e ele verifica se bate com o esperado. É importante que eles estejam devidamente criptografados, e uma forma simples de fazer isso é usar o HTTPS. Mas acho que os detalhes para isso já são escopo para outra pergunta.

Comment: Victor, então quer dizer que não existe uma forma mais rápida de fazer essa "seleção" dos fornecedores? Com relação ao HTTPS, vou procurar saber, mas queria saber do seguinte, pro app ser reconhecido pelo servidor, antes mesmo do usuário ser logado, acredito que o app tenha uma permissão e o usuário tenha outros tipos, não?

Comment: Eu não disse que não existe forma mais rápida, deve existir sim. Mas você não precisa se matar para achar a melhor solução que possa existir. Se você encontrar uma que funcione bem e de forma satisfatória, então já serve. Qualquer coisa, dá para otimizar e melhorar depois. Quanto ao servidor, estou supondo que o servidor é seu e a URL é sua, e portanto as conexões recebidas nesta URL só farão sentido se partirem do App que também é seu, e portanto você coloca lá no App, no server e na conexão o que você quiser, inclusive login+senha criptografado. Mas se não é bem esse o caso, explique melhor.

Comment: Victor, muito obrigado, vou tentar fazer e agora que achei esse fórum que tem pessoas que ajudam mesmo, acredito que vai ser mais tranquilo.

Comment: Com relação a autenticação do App no servidor, queria uma forma do App em si se autenticar no servidor, não sei se há necessidade, mas antes da autenticação do usuário, uma autenticação do próprio App, caso alguém "descubra" a URL, evitar ataques, não sei se é necessário.

Comment: @brenoguto Posso pensar em várias maneiras de autenticar, mas estes detalhes não são muito a minha praia. Acho que isso daí já vale uma nova pergunta. :)